# what drives "reflow/layout" times in Chrome & other browsers

Tags: performance, google-chrome, web-applications

When using an application developed with backbone.js Chrome freezes for about 7-10 seconds when adding to the DOM the content of a large document that has been retrieved with an AJAX call. Chrome's event timeline shows that the main issue is a single 'layout' event that takes about 6-8 seconds (times measured in a modern MB Air if that matters)

The content being loaded is about 800kbs of uncompressed HTML, 15000 DOM nodes, memory usage after the content is loaded is about to 30-35 Mbs; it's a large document but such a long freeze just doesn't feel right.

- **is such a large "layout" time to be expected** for a document like that, or is this a sign of other issues? (like too complex CSS rules, bad HTML structure, etc.)
- **what other factors** besides document size may have an impact in the performance of the 'layout' event?
- besides the obvious and probably right solution of breaking the content in pieces, **is there any trick that can be done to make it easier for the browser to compute the layout event**? (I am thinking in something like placing the monster content inside an iframe or a div with fixed positioning, or avoiding specific CSS features inside the content)